# It is possible to configure DNS to mirror a URL that points to a URL with a Query string?

Tags: dns

It is possible to configure DNS to mirror a URL that points to a URL with a Query string?

In this scenario I want

```
http://payment.mywebsite.com
```

to point to

```
http://paymentprovider.com&querystring
```

This payment provider uses a query string in the URL to whitelabel their product, providing the 'tailoring' of the branding based on the query string parameter in the URL.

I don't want a redirect. I want the customer to see the original URL when they reach the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. DNS is only responsible for *domain names*, as its name suggests. It has absolutely nothing to do with *URLs*.

If you want to mask a URL, a reverse proxy would be a solution. Any time someone sends a request to your proxy A, it internally requests B?foo=bar and returns the response.

Comment: Could the URL point to an IP, and the IP to a query string? (Quick google suggests apache mod rewrite could do this)

Comment: URLs are resolved to an IP through DNS based on the *host name* in the URL. So, the host name of the URL resolves to an IP, then an HTTP request requesting the *path and query parameters* of the URL is sent to that IP. In short, not really. Again, if you want the client to send a request to A but the request really goes to B, the client cannot know about B at all; a proxy is the only real solution.